# A href tel: transform to a link unavailable

Tags: numbers, href

In my WordPress website, I have something like that :

```
<a href="‭tel:+33752974531">TEXTE</a>
```

(false telephone number)

But, when I show the website, with Chrome or Safari, the link generated is : 
https://example.com/%E2%80%ADtel:+33752974531

In Chrome Inspector, I have :
[clic for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYpO1.png)

I tried to disable all JS files, and place my code somewhere else, but the result is the same...

Do you have an idea what's the problem ?

Comment: Here a screenshot of the problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tBSZ.png

Maybe it's a problem with my theme : Underscores... I keep search what cause this problem...

Comment: Hum... I don't know how, but I found a solution. I deleted all numbers and re-type every number. And now, it works ! Thanks :)